# Nginx: redirect from https to http except in wordpress login areas

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx

I'm trying to configure Nginx for a wordpress install. I'm using the wordpress plugin wp-https which handles redirects on the login page from http to https. Then my nginx server looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 66.175.215.82:80;
        listen 66.175.215.82:443 ssl;
        server_name some.domain.com; 

        root /var/www;
        index index.php index.html redirect.php;

        include /var/www/nginx.conf;

        #For HTTPS
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/self-signed/commons-dev.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/self-signed/commons-dev.key;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        # PHP-FPM
        location ~ \.php {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_pass php;
        }
}
```

The problems are that:

- AFAIK, Nginx doesn't support "not" locations, so I can't say "for all pages that *aren't* /wp-login."
- Redirecting wholesale from https to http will cause a redirect loop

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove the wordpress plugin and have nginx handle it all. Redirect all requests to http followed by a location match for wp-login.php that does nothing.

```
location / {¬
    server_name some.domain.com *.some.domain.com;
    return 301 http://some.domain.com$request_uri;
}

location /wp-login.php {
}
```

I imagine you'd also want all traffic at /wp-admin/ to ssl as well. It might be easier to have all ssl traffic on a subdomain:`ssl.some.domain.com` and then disallow traffic to /wp-login.php and wp-admin areas on the regular domain.